# Which google jar files to compile when using these import

Tags: android, google-maps, google-plus-signin

First i was using

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2
```

so i was getting an error message now i am using

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
```

But still these import file need some compile file to import these lib.

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.2'
```

The package name is (as far as I know) always the dependencie name as well. So `com.google.android.gms.**location**.xyz` is contained in `com.google.android.gms:play-services-**location**:a.b.c`.

Further you should update all 9.0.2 dependencies to the current 9.4.0:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.4.0'
```

Comment: Can you tell me compile file for this also                                                    import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.4.0' of course. Please mark the answer as correct if I could help you ;)

Comment: Thank You I Marked It :)