# Where can I find progaurd.config file in android studio. How to resolve error GRADLE SYNC error basic functionalities

Tags: android-studio

My android studio is not generating progaurd.config file. How I fix this error. Also. Gradle sync failed due to errors in basic functionalities.

Any one please provide me a solution.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Gradle sync failed: Gradle DSL method not found: 'classpath()'.

Comment: these are the errors

Comment: please provide me a solution

Comment: also in need of solution for progaurd.config file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37672099/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-classpath) SO question?

Comment: Thank you.Dsl method error is solved.but now it produces new errors.

Comment: Error:(30, 13) Failed to resolve: com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.7
Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.6
Error:(46, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2

Comment: these are the new errors that takes place after Dsl method is solved

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941712/which-google-jar-files-to-compile-when-using-these-import) or [this](http://onetouchcode.com/2016/07/02/crashlytics-for-android-apps) could help.